# How do I eliminate the "NAs introduced by coercion." warning?

Tags: r

For a coursera project, I needed to extract the row of a dataframe with the minimum value in a particular column. To this end, I coded:

```
 else if (outcome=="heart failure") {
    df1 <- subset(df, State == state)
    df1C<- df1[complete.cases(df1),]
    df2<- df1C[df1C$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure==min(as.numeric(df1C$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure), na.rm=TRUE),]
    print(df2[,2])
}
```

While I get the correct answer, I also get a warning: "NAs introduced by coercion."

I had two questions:

i. How could I improve the code so as to eliminate the warning?

ii. Is there a way to make make this less cumbersome - I feel the need to use "as.numeric" and the long column title make things very messy?

Comment: If the column contains numeric data, then ideally you should convert it to numeric right after you first read in the data. Then you don't have to remember to do it everytime you're going to use it. Also, rename the column right after you read the data. A column name that long is very clunky to work with.

Comment: Wrap `as.numeric()` with `suppressWarnings()`

Comment: You should not eliminate the warning: it tells you something about the data (namely that although the data _look_ numeric, they are stored as strings). You can do the conversion to numeric when the file is read using _e.g._ the `na.strings` and `colClasses` options to `read.table`. For less cumbersome code, look at `dplyr`.